# (CSS) Align div elements from center to left

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am trying to center one div element and make others float to the left from him like this:

[image: See in the picture]

In this code width and height is set to px but in my its in %. So I don't know where the center is. So it has to change with different resolution.
I don't want to put it in another div and center that because it center both divs and I want only yellow to be in center.

Is there any solution besides putting another empty div on the left side with same height as green has and making him invisible?

```css
.container{
    background-color:#34495e;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.in-center{
    background-color:#f1c40f;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.to-left{
    background-color:#2ecc71;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="in-center"></div>
        <div class="to-left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  background-color: #34495e;
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.in-center {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.to-left {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="in-center"></div>
  <div class="to-left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works but is text-align:center acceptable for centering divs?

Comment: It is for `inline-block` elements.